# How to pass from strong solution to classic solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In PDE theory, one can find a lot of results and definitions of strong solutions and under any assumptions one can consider a solution a strong one. For example, the case of Navier-Stokes equation: strong solution is when we part from initial data $u_0\in H^1$ and weak solution when we part from $u_0\in L^2$. My question is: what assumptions allow us to pass from the concept of strong to the concept of classic solution?